# PHP nested 'if' code troubleshooting to check recipient and sender message/email forwarding

Tags: php, email, if-statement, nested, xampp

I'm just working through sending e-mails from form (XAMPP on MACOS) and hitting a snag when using a nested 'if' to check forwarding to recipient and sender. I borrowed some code from other similar threads thank you. There are no PHP errors described in the browser when running the program but there is also no 'echo' executed and the form just resets. I suspect I just made an error with the nesting? Also I'm not using an 'else' HEREDOC at the end of the PHP code but that wasn't an issue with single message/email version of the file. Any time saving suggestions appreciated!

```
<?php
//check form submit
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "Submit")){
  $submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Submit");
  $to  = "example@gmail.com";
  $from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Email");
  $first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "First_Name");
  $last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Last_Name");
  $subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Subject");
  $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission;". " " . $subject;
  $message= $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Message");
  $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Message");
  $headers = "From:" . $from;
  $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    //check first mail sent
    if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
        //check second mail sent
        if (mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2)) {
            return true;
            //if both conditions met
            if (true) {echo "SUCCESS";
                      } else {
                echo "ERROR";
            }
        //close second mail check
        }
        //close first mail check
    }
    //close form submit check
}
?>
```

Utilising the code suggested in below answer appears to make no difference to the outcome described above.

```
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
    //check second mail sent
    if (mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2)) {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
  //end check mails
    }
//end check form submit
}
?>
```

It was exactly that which prompted a search of the topic with 'return true' being the more common suggestion for handling nested 'if' statements. It appeared to work ok with a similar file that sent the INPUT_POST from a seperate HTML file (code below) but it's possible that has the error also? I also tried a few other strategies like '&&', 'and' with the two 'mail' calls but those consistently caused parsing errors.

```
<?php
$to  = "example@gmail.com";
$from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Email");
$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "First_Name");
$last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Last_Name");
$subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Subject");
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission;". " " . $subject;
$message= $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Message");
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Message");
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
    if (mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2)) {
        return true;
    }
}
if (true) { echo "SUCCESS";
           //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('SUCCESS');</script>";
          } else { echo "ERROR";
                  //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ERROR');</script>";
                 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEAR Mail appears to provide a solution that works:

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "Submit")){
$submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Submit");
require "Mail.php";
$to      = "example@hotmail.com";
$from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Email");
$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "First_Name");
$last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Last_Name");
$subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Subject");
$message= $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Message");  
$host    = "smtp.gmail.com";
$port    =  "587";
$user    = "example@gmail.com";
$pass    = "EnterYourPassword";
$headers = array("From"=> $from, "To"=>$to, "Subject"=>$subject);
$smtp    = @Mail::factory("smtp", array("host"=>$host, "port"=>$port, "auth"=> true, "username"=>$user, "password"=>$pass));
$mail    = @$smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
$mail2   = @$smtp->send($from, $headers, $message);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)){
        echo "error: {$mail->getMessage()}";
        if (PEAR::isError($mail2)){
            echo "error: {$mail2->getMessage()}";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Message sent";
    }
}
?>
```

The nesting between the *ifs* and the *else* is important as the script may send the message/mail successfully but not execute the echo, or worse. Going back to check that code structure with the regular PHP *Mail* again appeared to produce no change in outcome as described in OP. For anyone having persistent authentication errors with gmail with all other avenues failing here is a link that worked for me but I have to use it regularly along with occasionally clearing the caches and resetting the servers. https://g.co/allowaccess
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect. The mail function returns a `true` already so your

```
if (true) {echo "SUCCESS";
```

is not needed and the `return true` should be removed so your script doesn't terminate.

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.

-https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
    //check second mail sent
    if (mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2)) {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
```

You also need an `else` on your first `if` because you'll never enter the second if the first fails.

```
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
        //check second mail sent
        if (mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2)) {
            echo "SUCCESS";
        } else {
            echo "ERROR";
        }
} else {
    echo "Error from first mail call";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, new code below with no change in outcome>

Comment: Please edit the question to show new code https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59024889/edit. Cant read in comments

Comment: I've been trying to configure smtp with XAMPP on Mac which I found troublesome, the suggestions on Stack Overflow were mainly directed at windows, the difference from what I can tell is that the Mac version does not have a sendmail.ini file but a sendmail.php and sendmail.pdf (etc folder). I went through the instructions in the pdf for smtp and php  mailer but neither worked even after reinstalling XAMP due to prior file changes. At that point I decided to use the echo execution as a measure the performance of the php script (ignoring e-mail not being sent yet) which could be a mistake?

Comment: You need an `else` on the first `if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {` as well. otherwise you won't enter the second `if` and your `error` output will never render. Not sure what you are asking about server configuration, thats a different question though

Comment: I don't follow, usually 'else if' would follow the first 'if', are you able to edit your answer with the correct code that renders successfully? The server configuration was context.

Comment: PEAR mail is much easier to set up on XAMPP-Mac once I overcame the gmail security which is a ballache, at least on my computer, thank you web. Once the mail is consistently sending there is probably no need to check both mails (although it's probably better practice?) as it's from the same sender and the echo/alert is only an indicator, not the confirmation. I might take another look at that code for interest's sake down the track but didn't want to waste too much time on it now as it's only the testing environment and should be much less problematic on a commercial web host/server.Thank you!

Comment: I quickly checked your new code snippet, no change in outcome as described in OP.